# Make wrapper div shrink around dynamic, responsive image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shrinkwrap

After countless look-ups, I still can't get an definitive answer.

I need a div to wrap around a responsive image, but the image

- is of unkwown dimensions
- should have a height of 70% of wrapper, but the width can be anything, according to dimension ratio.
- should keep dimension ratio when window sized up and down (at the moment only keeps dimension ratio when scaling up)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8c15uw1d/

```
div {
height: 60%;
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid brown;
}
img {
height: 70%;
width:auto:
display: block;
}
```

Strangely in IE9 this works as required, but in Chrome the image scales up over the div, doesn't 'take it along'.

1. How do I achieve this? I strongly suspect it could only be done with JS.
2. If I indeed need to do this in Jquery (on browser resize) - say I have 100 of these images of 400px x 200px on the page, will site performance be significantly impaired each time the window is resized? Is this considered bad practise?

Comment: Can you just have the div scale to 70% and have the image fill the div?

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/1pymnghf/ - Brown border doesn't scale with img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("div").css("width", ($("img").width() / $(window).width()) * 100 + "%");
});
```

Since CSS wasn't working perfectly for me, I used JQuery to cater for the width change.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8c15uw1d/7/)

Basically the CSS already lets the image resize as per ration. The JQuery code gets the percentage width of the `img` tag and sets it as the `div` width in percentage, causing the container to always wrap around the image when the window is resized.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this will be my only option. Pitty, as IE performance on browser resize is laggy. Do you know what the performance implications are for adjusting multiple images each time window is resized?

Comment: I am not sure about the performance with 100 images, but I'd say its a 50-50, since the JQuery code is only setting the width in terms of percentage. The actual `div` resize is being done by the browser rendering itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want the div to shrink in width, but here css for having the ratio kept. I believe this will scale well on a computer, perhaps not on a mobile device (for 100s of images). Perhaps consider making it fetch more when scroll reach bottom (like google images search).

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

div {
height: 60%;
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid brown;
}

img {
max-height: 70%;
max-width: 100%;
width:auto:
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd like the Div to shrink and expand in width when expanding browser window vertically. Unfortunately this doesn't make the image scale up in width, it only scales down with aspect ratio and scales up only in height (not width) - I've even tried max-width:200%, still the brown bordered div doesn't scale with image: http://jsfiddle.net/34LvqL10/

Comment: @petestar i have changed the height of img to max-height. This will keep the aspect even better. What is the maximum width of the div? How do you want it to scale?

Comment: There is no maximum width, basically I want the image to scale up and down, height 80% and width:auto. The question is around getting the containing div to scale with the image.

Comment: Since the img is in the div it's the div that controls the size. I'm not sure what it os you're trying to do, but perhaps you should have the div and image as siblings and then position the div relative to the image..?